# how do you forward http/www to https/non-www on windows hosting iis?

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm really struggling with this. I have tried no end of examples and everything I read tells me this should work, however, I'm no server expert so I may well have made some incorrect assumptions about what I have done.

Quite simply I have a site at https://xxxxx.co.uk if someone types in

- http://xxxxx.co.uk or
- http://www.xxxxx.co.uk or
- https://www.xxxxx.co.uk

I want them to be redirected to https://xxxxx.co.uk

Currently, I can get the Http to https working but not the www to non-www part (with or without the https bit). It just stays on the www.xxxxx.co.uk (http://www and https://www) and tells me about a security risk which makes sense. But I want it to go to my site.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been at this all day.

I found this article [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533869/iis-redirect-www-to-non-www-and-http-to-https-is-it-possible-to-do-it-with-only?rq=1) which covers nearly all scenarios except https://www.xxxxx.co.uk. This rule just doesn't seem to want to work

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>

    <rules>

        <rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://xxxxx.co.uk" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>     

        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="(.*)" /> 
            <conditions> 
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions> 
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule> 

    </rules>

</rewrite>
```

Comment: I tested your code, and the www to non-www part can work on my side. please show me the security risk messgae, This problem seems to be caused by your certificate being invalid.

Comment: https://www.xxxxx.co.uk. This is the only rule doesn't seem to want to work

Comment: Can you post your error message?